# Android- Google Maps V2 Authorization Failure. Impossible to load map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i am, after two days of struggling and searching through all articles possible on internet on Google Maps authorization failure i finally decided to ask you help.

I have to specific that i did all the steps required to make it work:

1. Set up the Google Maps V2 for android in Google console.
2. Update my manifest with the API key and permissions
3. Import the library

After all those steps i am unable to load my map. This it's driving me crazy i don't know what to do anymore. I am saying this once more. I read all the questions on StackOverflow regarding this problem i cannot resolve it.

here's my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.dorelljobs"
 android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.ApplicationContextProvider"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.LoginActivity"
        android:label="Dorell"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.dorelljobs.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.SIGNUP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.dorelljobs.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="424080351070286" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.LostPassActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lost_pass"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.dorelljobs.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.LOSTPASS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.dorelljobs.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="jobs.JobsListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jobs_list"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.dorelljobs.JOBSLIST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the pain i managed to resolve the problem. You have to do all the steps i did earlier and besides this download via Eclipse software downloader the Keytool software and i created a new Key Certificate. That was all